# Adding a variable to all ajax calls

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a variable that I wish to add to all my ajax calls, how is this possible.

I have tried the `ajaxSetup` like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
data: {'language': 'ENU'}
});
```

But the preset variable (language) gets overwritten as soon as I specify the data parameter in the actual call.

Comment: You should define you're global parameters in an object, and use jquery extent do add new parameters to the glonal ones. [jquery extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery API documentation "[All subsequent Ajax calls using any function will use the new settings, unless overridden by the individual calls, until the next invocation of $.ajaxSetup().](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)".

This should be true for the `data` attribute to. Make sure you don't specify `data` for your individual ajax calls or read the data *before* setting it to verify that your set default is there and then append to that.